# Jewish Souls and Gentile Souls

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Were Adam and Eve and Noah Jewish? Are we to consider them Gentiles? If they are Gentiles, are we to consider their souls different from Jewish souls?

Comment: How do you define "Jewish"?

Comment: Adam was not Jewish.

Answer (score 0):

The [Parshas Derachim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48331&st=&pgnum=18) asks about Avraham and his descendants after they had a circumcision. He has a back and forth there.

From the question it implies that anyone earlier was definitely not Jewish